# Matplotlib: How to remove axis and set facecolor in a rotated axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the following code to plot some circle and rotate the axes:-

```py
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.grid_finder import DictFormatter
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes as floating_axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def setup_axes1(fig, rect, angle):
    tr = Affine2D().scale(2, 2).rotate_deg(angle)

    grid_helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(
        tr, extremes=(0, 11, 0, 11)
    )

    ax1 = floating_axes.FloatingSubplot(fig, rect, grid_helper=grid_helper)


    fig.add_subplot(ax1) 
    aux_ax = ax1.get_aux_axes(tr)

    return aux_ax

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20), facecolor="#222222")

fig.delaxes(axes)

ax = setup_axes1(fig, 121, -45)

# NOT WORKING
ax.set_facecolor("#222222")

ax.set_aspect("equal")

count = 1

for x in coord[::-1]:
    for y in coord:
        if count <= 55:
            color, radius, hatch_num, lw, fill = "gold", 0.4, 0, 1, "gold"
        else:
            color, radius, hatch_num, lw, fill = "grey", 0.27, 3, 0, None
            
        circle = plt.Circle((y,x), radius=radius, linewidth=lw, fill=fill, hatch=hatch_num*'-', color=color)
        ax.add_artist(circle)
        
        count += 1

# NOT WORKING        
ax.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

The following code is giving me this output:
[image]

The only thing here is when I am setting a facecolor and tuning off the axis in the code it is not working. It is my first time trying to make a rotated axis plot, so don't know how to do it.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed here is the updated code:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.grid_finder import DictFormatter
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes as floating_axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def setup_axes1(fig, rect, angle):
    tr = Affine2D().scale(2, 2).rotate_deg(angle)

    grid_helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(
        tr, extremes=(0, 11, 0, 11)
    )

    ax1 = floating_axes.FloatingSubplot(fig, rect, grid_helper=grid_helper)

    # added lines
    ax1.axis("off")    
    ax1.axis["bottom"].set_visible(False)
    ax1.axis["top"].set_visible(False)
    ax1.axis["right"].set_visible(False)
    ax1.axis["left"].set_visible(False)

    fig.add_subplot(ax1)
    
    aux_ax = ax1.get_aux_axes(tr)

    return aux_ax

coord = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20), facecolor="#222222")

fig.delaxes(axes)

ax = setup_axes1(fig, 121, -45)

ax.set_aspect("equal")

count = 1

for x in coord[::-1]:
    for y in coord:
        if count <= 55:
            color, radius, hatch_num, lw, fill = "gold", 0.4, 0, 1, "gold"
        else:
            color, radius, hatch_num, lw, fill = "grey", 0.27, 3, 0, None
            
        circle = plt.Circle((y,x), radius=radius, linewidth=lw, fill=fill, hatch=hatch_num*'-', color=color)
        ax.add_artist(circle)
        
        count += 1

plt.show()
```

Here is the output:
[image]